# My faces won't fill ( Blender 2.9)

Tags: modeling, interface, constraints, selection-tools, blend-files

Working on a human character and when i try to add faces to attach the body it wouldn't work .. Tried F , Alt + F. Relatively new to blender.

Also tried on a basic cube still won't fill in faces.
[image: The body i'm working on]

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have 2 objects, because there are 2 origins.
First Join objects (cmd/ctrl + J).
And yes, Joonas is right you have doubles (> Merge by distance).

Answer (score 0):

Are they two separate objects or one? The meshes need to be one object before you can join faces. Once they are a single object, selecting the same number of parallel edges should allow you to fill the empty face. If that doesn't work, take a full-screen snapshot or possibly upload your file.

Comment: Try Looptools: W > Bridge. Select two edges you want to connect and use Looptools.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices as can be seen from black dots with orange rods. Press <kbd>A</kbd>  in *Edit Mode* to select all vertices and from *Mesh* drop down (or pop-up) menu select *Clean Up* > *Merge by Distance*.

You can also select vertices and press <kbd>F3</kbd>  and search *Merge by Distance*.

Next try filling again.

Answer (score 0):

Cant close face because clipping is on.